# How to achieve bulk save using spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using `@Tranaction` level method annotation. I have tried multiple ways but  records are inserted one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Hibernate you need to enable batching explicitly, use these properties 
in *application.properties*

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```